# Samsung A21s software fastboot is disabled

Tags: adb, samsung, fastboot, bootloader

I have a Samsung Galaxy A21s phone that I am trying to install Android 12 on. I have unlocked the bootloader, I go into the recovery mode and I select bootloader, however when I get there, it is just some red text saying "Entering fastboot mode..." and then it gets stuck there.

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening, and if there is any way to fix it without carting it off to Samsung?

Comment: Fastboot _is_ the bootloader. I don't know specifics of this model, but what you're describing sounds about right. Try `fastboot devices`.

Comment: @gronostaj I ran the command, it just returned an empty line and then quit. No errors or anything.

Comment: You need Odin or Heimdall software to flash ROMs on Samsung devices, fastboot is not used for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung devices only have a placeholder Fastboot mode. It doesn't actually serve any purpose. Please use Download Mode instead.

Comment: How do I do this then?

Comment: Usually, running `adb reboot download` while in Android should be sufficient.